# Why can't I include the SPM TSCUtility library as a dependency in my Package.swift?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I want to include the TSCUtility library of the [Swift Package Manager](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager)  (SPM) in my project.

The specific library is defined in SPM's `Package.swift` as follows:

```
   ...
   .library(
        name: "TSCUtility",
        targets: [
            "TSCclibc",
            "TSCLibc",
            "TSCBasic",
            "TSCUtility",
        ]
    ),
    ...
```

When I build my project, I get the following error:

```
swift build --product nfgz
'ngfz' /Users/nlykkei/Projects/ngfz: error: product dependency 'TSCUtility' not found
warning: dependency 'SwiftPM' is not used by any target
```

suggesting that the library couldn't be found. However, if I instead put another SPM library as a dependency, e.g. `SwiftPM`, then everything works fine?

My Package.swift is defined as follows:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.0
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "ngfz",
    products: [
        .executable(
            name: "ngfz",
            targets: ["ngfz"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager.git", from: "0.1.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "ngfz",
            dependencies: ["TSCUtility"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "ngfzTests",
            dependencies: ["ngfz"]),
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, the last tagged version is 0.4.0, in which the utility library is still named `SPMUtility`. You can get the latest version by declaring a dependency on the `master` branch:

```swift
dependencies: [
    .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager.git", .branch("master"))
],
```

Comment: Thanks. So `.branch` is targeting a specific branch, where as `.from` is only about tagged versions, i.e. commits that have a tag specified (every commit may not have a tag) - am I right? :-)